# Ajax Post script not working in PrettyPhoto js form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, prettyphoto

I have created a form as inline content in prettyPhoto. Form popup works fine. 
On the submit of the form I have a Ajax post script which calls php script for sending email. But this Ajax post call, does not work. Trying to figure out how to add the ajax script on form submit inside prettyPhoto.

**Ajax script**

```
$("#getStartedForm").submit(function() {
    alert("form works!");
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "send_mail11.php",
        dataType : "html",
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend : function() {
            $("#loadingNews").show();
        },
        success : function(response) {
            $("#responseNews").html(response);
            $("#loadingNews").hide();
            $('#responseNews').delay(5000).fadeOut();
            $('#subscribeInput').val("");
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="demoform" rel="prettyPhoto">Start</a>
<div id="demoform">
<form id="getStartedForm" action="#" method="post">
<div id="responsenews"></div>
<input type="text" id="firstName"/>
<input type="text" id="eMail"/>
<textarea id="commmentBox"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="send mail"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u please create the fiddle for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Photo is cloning the inline element inside it's container so your events bind to DOM of actual inline element will not work.

You can try with ajax solution or do some customized coding by hooking to the events of Pretty Photo to initialize your submit event binding to the cloned element.

Comment: can you try with changepicturecallback: function(){}, /* Called everytime an item is shown/changed */